# HTTP request with C#

Tags: c#, http, xmlhttprequest

I want to convert the Object received in the function and do as needed to convert it to an object `({"some_key": "some_value"})`.

**Here is my code:**

```
public HttpRequests(string url, string method, Object data)
{

   //The following prepares data, according to received parameter

    if (data is Array)
    {
        data = (Array)data;
    }
    else if (data is Dictionary<Object, Object>)
    {
        data = ((Dictionary<string, string>)data)["something"] = platform_secret;
        data = ((Dictionary<string, string>)data)["something2"] = "1";
    }

    method = method.ToUpper(); //POST or GET

    this.url = just_url + url;
    this.data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    this.method = method;

}

public Object performRequest()
{

    if (this.data != null && url != null)
    {

        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        byte[] data_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToChar(data)[]);
        //^ this does not work. Am I supposed to do this?
        // as I said, what I want is to get an object {key: something} that can be read
        //      by $_POST["key"] in the server

        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; //TODO: check
        //request.ContentLength = ((Dictionary<string, string>) data);
        request.ContentLength = data_bytes.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //TODO: not async at the moment

        //{BEGIN DOUBT

        dataStream.Write(data_bytes, 0, data_bytes.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //DOUBT: DO THIS ^ or THIS:_      ???

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dataStream);
        writer.Write(this.data);

        //End DOUBT}

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

        writer.Close();
        response.Close();
        dataStream.Close();

        return dataResponse.

    }
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to debug what's in `this.data`? Also you are using `data` instead of `this.data`

Comment: your code is incorrect or incomplete. The top function has no return type or function name and variable platform_secret and just_url are not defined. Can you supply working code?

Comment: Please add clear explanation of your problem or question. “What am I missing” is not a real question.

Comment: if you're on .NET 4.5 or greater, just use `HttpClient` instead. I've found it much easier to work with. I remember reading a while ago (can't find the source now) that M$ is promoting developers to use `HttpClient` over `HttpWebRequest` anyway.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

As you initially assign `this.data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);`, suppose his.data has type string (you can change if it is otherwise).

Then instead of `byte[] data_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToChar(data)[]);` you need to write just `byte[] data_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);`

After use this

```
//{BEGIN DOUBT

        dataStream.Write(data_bytes, 0, data_bytes.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
```

It will help to do the call with some data but it does not help to solve your problem.  `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` does not expect that the data is `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` serialized. It expects a string containing & separated pairs that are urlencoded.

```
name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

So, you need to use this format instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the first piece of code. [Here is and exmaple.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
But the second piece could work too, I guess. You have missed nothing on C# side. A problem could be in the data you are going to transfer, however. If it is not correctly encoded, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something closer to the lines of this...

```
void Main()
{

    var formSerializer = new FormEncodedSerializer();
    formSerializer.Add("key", "value");
    formSerializer.Add("foo", "rnd");
    formSerializer.Add("bar", "random");

    var uri = @"http://example.com";
    var contentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var postData = formSerializer.Serialize();
    var http = new Http();

    Console.WriteLine (http.Post(uri, postData, contentType));
}


public class Http
{
    public string Post(string url, string data, string format)
    {
        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var contentLength = content.Length;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.ContentType = format;
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}`


public class FormEncodedSerializer
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> formKeysPairs;

    public FormEncodedSerializer(): this(new Dictionary<string, string>())
    {
    }

    public FormEncodedSerializer(Dictionary<string, string> kvp)
    {
        this.formKeysPairs = kvp;
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        formKeysPairs.Add(key, value);
    }  

    public string Serialize()
    {
        return string.Join("", this.formKeysPairs.Select(f => string.Format("&{0}={1}", f.Key,f.Value))).Substring(1);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.formKeysPairs.Clear();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not really understand what your service expects, in which format you have to send the data.
Anyway, if you set ContentType like "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", you must encode your data with this format. You can simply do it with this code;

```
var values = ((Dictionary<string, string>)data).Aggregate(
                    new NameValueCollection(),
                    (seed, current) =>
                    {
                        seed.Add(current.Key, current.Value);
                        return seed;
                    });
```

So, your data is sent like "something=platform_secret&something2=1"

Now, you can send form data simply:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var result = client.UploadValues(url, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first function with signature `public HttpRequests(string url, string method, Object data)` dosn't seem have any logical error but in your second function with signature `public Object performRequest()` you have some issue:

- if your HTTP method is GET you don't need to write content stream.
- if your method is POST and your data are JSON you need setting up HTTP requester like this:

  ```
  request.ContentType = "application/json";
  ```

and finally, flush your stream before you close it, like this `request.Flush();`